# about the following differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please check the screenshot. I am not sure which part is wrong about my answer.

[image: question and my answer]

Comment: Did you try with absolute value ?

Comment: i did, still incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'-2=e^{y-2x+2}$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(y-2x)'=e^2e^{y-2x}$$
$$e^{-(y-2x)}d(y-2x)=e^2dx$$
Integrate
$$e^{2x-y}=-e^2x+C$$
Apply initial condition 
$$y(0)=-2 \implies C=e^2$$

Finally,
$$|2x-y|=\ln |1-x|\color {blue}{+2}$$

Comment: F(x,y)=1, rewrite ur answer as F(x,y)=ln|1−x|-|2x−y|+3, still incorrect

Comment: You shouldn't bother because your answer is correct. There are many trouble with website like that @HongmoLiu

Answer (score 1):

$$y'-2=e^{y-2x+2}$$

Substitute $v(x)=y-2x$ which gives $v'=\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=y'-2$. Therefore

$$v'=e^{v+2}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{e^{v+2}}\,dv=dx \implies e^{-v}\,dv=e^2\,dx$$
integrating and solving for $v$ forms
$$v=-\log|c_1-e^2x|$$
so that
$$y=2x-\log|c_1-e^2x|$$
the initial condition of $y(0)=-2$ produces

$$c_1=e^{2}$$

therefore

$$y=2x-\log|e^{2}-e^2x|=2x-\log|1-x|-2$$

Comment: still in correct by the website

Comment: How are you entering the solution (and what is the website)? Does $F(x,y)=y-2x+\log|1-x|+2$ work? Do you need to set $F(x,y)=y-2x+\log|1-x|+2=1$?

Comment: thanks for your help. it appears to be a bug and they fixed it.